# Animating form size

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, css, animation

i want to animate the height of an input form when the user first selects it. So the form is only say 1 line high, they go to type in it and it becomes about 10 lines high.

Comment: Read the jquery documentation, it  is very straightforward. element.animate(details):

Comment: also don't use an input, use a textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the 'css-only' way to do it.

Just use the :focus selector on the text area and change the height of the textarea in the focussed state

```
textarea{
    height:20px;
    width:150px;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

textarea:focus{
    height:50px;
}
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/NHZzt/

Comment: Could you complete your answer with proper information about the current state of CSS3 animations?

Comment: This is fantastic, just what i was after. But would there be a simple way to make the form stay at the larger size after the user has written in it once?

Comment: I'm still kinda learning jquery and javascript, but this sounds simple enough. So I use the same css transitions as you did before, but instead of using the :focus, make it so when a .focus event is fired, I add a class which makes the text area longer? and let the css transitions do the animations?

Or will I have to animate the height of the text area with jquery alone?

Answer (score 0):

First you want to use a `<textarea/>` instead, this way you can manipulate the number of lines of text shown with the `rows` attribute. That is,

```
<textarea rows="10"></textarea>
```

displays an element of 10 lines of text.

Concerning the animation, you can use the `.animate()` method for a smooth transition while expanding and collapsing the number of lines of text.

I have wrap it in a jQuery plugin for easy of use.

```
$.fn.expandable = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        var $self = $(this);
        var isExpanded = false;
        var collapseTimeout;
        $self.on({
            focusin: function(evt) {
                if (isExpanded || evt.keyCode < 46 && evt.keyCode != 8 && evt.keyCode != 32) 
                    return true;
                isExpanded = true;
                clearTimeout(collapseTimeout);
                $self.stop(true).animate({
                    rows: 10
                }, "slow");
            },
            focusout: function() {
                collapseTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
                    $self.stop(true).animate({
                        rows: 1
                    }, "slow");
                }, 200);
                isExpanded = false;
            }
        });
    });
};
```

The `focusin` event handler will expand the element to display 10 lines of text. It will also clear the collapse timeout set to change the display to 1 line of text after the element has lost focus. The collapse timeout is set in the `focusout` event handler.

The animation speed is set to `slow`, the collapse timeout to `200` ms and the number of lines of text to be expanded to is `10` lines of text.

The following will initialize all the `textarea` elements in the page:

```
$("textarea").expandable();
```

[You can see a live example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/2P94e/)